# Create a delegate when there is a conditional attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, delegates, portable-class-library

I have a Portable Class Library with a class `PCLDebug`:

```
public static class PCLDebug {
    public static Action<string> LogLine { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is set things up once in the outer project, then be able to call `LogLine` within the PCL to print stuff to the VS Output window.  Here is my attempt:

```
MyPCL.PCLDebug.LogLine = System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine;
```

The problem here is that the compiler complains, because System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine has a conditional attribute of Debug:

> Cannot create delegate with 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string)' because it has a Conditional attribute

I am actually fine with it if the `LogLine` call only works in the debugging environment.  But how do I keep the compiler happy?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could try wrapping it in a lambda function:

```
MyPCL.PCLDebug.LogLine = s => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( s ); };
```

Comment: Why does this work but it doesn't work assigning directly?

Comment: @reggaeguitar Because `ConditionalAttribute` causes the compiler to omit calls to the function, but direct assignment isn't a call, it's actually delegate construction, so it can't be omitted.  The lambda works because it creates an anonymous function that either does nothing or calls the conditional function.  In either case the delegate is definitely assigned.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this alternative notation too:

```
    MyPCL.PCLDebug.LogLine = delegate(string text) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text); };
```